# Print to console with Jetty

Tags: console, jetty

I am creating a simple Jetty server and am wondering how to print something into the console, like variables at specific times or when a user connects. I am compiling the Jetty server with a java class with jetty-all jar files. I am not using any xml currently. Could anyone tell me how to print something into the console? Such as, when a user connects say, "User connected"

Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate question to: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14493568/775715 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/14468812/775715

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You better should output to a log file, you could use `log4j` for that.
Use

```
LOGGER.info("user connected");
```

on linux you then can use

```
tail -f logfile.log
```

to live output the content to the console